# Parámetros opcionales en rutas angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router, frontend

como lo dice el titulo tengo una ruta  en esta ruta puede o no llegarme un id  y cuando tenga ese id necesito hacer una peticion http para recoger unos datos de una api
de esta manera coloque mi router-module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AddpaymentComponent } from './pages/addpayment/addpayment.component';
import { PaymentlistComponent } from './pages/paymentlist/paymentlist.component';
const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: '',
    children: [
      { path:'add/:id?',component:AddpaymentComponent },
      { path:'list',component:PaymentlistComponent },
      { path:'**',redirectTo:'home' },
    ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class PaymentsRoutingModule { }


{ path:'add/:id?',component:AddpaymentComponent },
```

En esta sección coloque el id? como parámetro opcional y todo funciona pero el problema esta cuando quiero conseguir ese id uso el siguiente método

```
getId():void{
    this.subscriptions.push(this._route.params.subscribe(
      response=>{
        if(response){ 
          this.id = response.id;
          console.log(response,response.id);
        }
      }, 
      err=>{
        console.log(err);
      }
    ));
  }
```

Entonces los valores están en mi response pero no se como acceder a ellos esta es la foto de la respuesta :

```
{id?: '7'}id?: "7"[[Prototype]]: Object undefined
```

Cómo puedo acceder a ese dato puesto que colocar params.id? no es valido
o que estoy haciendo mal como podría pasar ese parámetro de manera opcional ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En las rutas el caracter `?` no hace que el parámetro sea opcional sino que se convierte en un caracter más del nombre del parámetro.

Para lograr lo que deseas puedes usar dos rutas, una con parámetro y otra sin parámetro:

```
 { path:'add/:id',component:AddpaymentComponent },
 { path:'add',component:AddpaymentComponent },
```

Comment: thanks my friend ajajjaa